# Having trouble comparing two strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to take in two strings via command line arguments in C and then compare them. I know that `malloc` returns a `void` pointer although I do not understand how to pass this to my compare function because it is looking for a `const void` pointer. I assume I will have to cast the pointers that point to the memory on the heap where the strings will be allocated (?) although I'm not sure how to go about this, any help is appreciated.

```
int cmpstringp(const void *arg1, const void *arg2);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *strOne;
    char *strTwo;
    int n = 10;
    strOne = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strTwo = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strOne = argv[1];
    strTwo - argv[2];
    cmpstringp(strOne, strTwo);
}

int cmpstringp(const void *arg1, const void *arg2) {
    const char * const * ptr1 = (const char **)arg1;
    const char * const * ptr2 = (const char **)arg2;

    const char *str1 = *ptr1; 
    const char *str2 = *ptr2;

    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

Comment: You can compare `argv[1]` to `argv[2]` directly: `strcmp(argv[1], argv[2])`.

Comment: You don’t need any allocations since on the next line you’re leaking the allocated memory away by assigning another value to the variables. There’s also no reason to cast into double pointer when they’re just pointers. Just use the pointers as they are.

Comment: you have `strTwo - argv[2];` in your code, probably should be `strTwo = argv[2];`, is that mistype or you run it?

Comment: All the comments/answers are right but no one has said what you did wrong: 1) `strOne = argv[1];` in your case causes a memory leak. If you wanted a copy use `strdup` or `strcpy` into the buffer you allocated. 2) `cmpstringp()` is a mess. You pass it pointers but then you treat the parameters as `**`

Comment: You're always allowed to pass a pointer to non-`const` to a function that expects `const`. The `const` in the function declaration just indicates that it will not modify the data, which is fine even though the argument data is modifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take a look at the return value of applying `strcmp` directly to `argv`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int ret;

    ret = strcmp(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (ret == 0)
        printf("Equal strings.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, if you're looking to have a function with generic arguments that compares two strings (i.e. to use in `qsort()`), here's how you could go about it:

```
int string_cmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
     return strcmp((const char*)a, (const char*)b);
}
```

Comment: `if(strcmp(argv[1], argv[2]) == 0)` would work too, unless you're paid by the line. ;-)

Comment: It would, but I thought of keeping the return value just in case you needed it for alphabetical sorting or something. Thank you though! :)

Comment: To avoid spurious warnings, I suggest `return strcmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b);` if C++ compatibility is useful or `return strcmp(a, b);` if not.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the tips, this helps a lot :)

Comment: @Jackson No problem :) If you liked my answer, please consider accepting it. Cheers!